# What's the Difference between xvda15 and root on AWS ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, disk-space-utilization

So I ran `df -hT` on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance to check the disk storage. I get the following response:

```
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4   7.6G  7.0G  671M  92% /
tmpfs          tmpfs  7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs  3.2G  920K  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda15    vfat   105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs  1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I'm trying to understand the difference between `/dev/root` and  `/dev/xvda15`. What's the difference between these two volumes? I was meaning to increase the volume but I realized that although my root is filled, my xvda15 is still empty. Any info shall be appreciated.

Comment: I don't entirely grok your question. They are two different partitions, for two different purposes. `xvda15` is a EFI boot volume.

Comment: So when I log into my ssg it says 90% disk storage used, so I thought maybe I should add some storage or optimal performance. But then I realized that xvda15 actually has 7.6gb empty. Does that mean I don't need to add storage? Or is xvda for totally different purposes?

Comment: xvda15 has 99MB free. Do you need more space? If so extend `/`. If not, well... then it's fine?

Comment: @vidarlo I do need more storge and I extended my volume to 15gb. However, I still get ' / is using 91.2% of 7.57GB '. I'm not sure if increasing the volume on AWS console means increasing the volume of root?

Comment: Nvm increasing it worked. I had to reboot it. Now I understand the difference between the different volumes. Thanks!